# Statically building Qt - Libraries are huge

Tags: qt, compilation

I am following the advice from this webpage: http://www.formortals.com/build-qt-static-small-microsoft-intel-gcc-compiler to try and build the libraries statically but the libraries that are being created are really large. Where some are in the order of 200 - 300MB each. A non-static link is creating files that are similar sized to the ones that are provided in the offline installer.

I am using Visual Studio 2008 to compile.

In qmake.conf I have set these:

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE = -O1 -GL -MT -MP2
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE = /INCREMENTAL:NO /NODEFAULTLIB:"MSVCRT"
```

Then I use this:

```
> configure -opensource -release -static -qt-libjpeg -qt-zlib -qt-libpng -nomake examples 
    -nomake demos -no-qt3support -no-scripttools -no-openssl -no-opengl -no-webkit 
    -no-phonon -no-style-motif -no-style-cde -no-style-cleanlooks -no-style-plastique 
    -no-sql-sqlite -platform win32-msvc2008
> nmake
```

Am I doing something wrong or are files of this size to be expected? I tried without the `/NODEFAULTLIB` but the size was the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is entirely to be expected. All functionality now is contained within the static library, where otherwise it would be in a DLL for a non-static link. Those libraries are only import libraries and therefore a significant amount smaller.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer (and quick edit on Qt which I just noticed, but not in time). I wasn't too familiar with building libraries like this and the webpage was talking about files of more like 13MB size so I was somewhat confused :-(

Comment: I believe they are still comparing DLL sizes there if I'm not mistaken? I haven't built Qt statically myself, so perhaps 200-300MB is somewhat on the large side, but I would not find that unexpected.